# I Cant View my posts for this Blog in the Index.html page

Tags: python, django

Hey guys i am to view my blog post, but i cannot seem to view any of the blog post on the loaded html page, what could be the problem i have tried to troubleshoot to see the problem but i cant come with any solution, please i would need some feedback on what i am doing wrong

my index

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content  %}
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
    }

    .head_text {
        color: white;
    }

    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
    }
</style>
<header class="masthead">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="site-heading">
                    <h3 class=" site-heading my-4 mt-3 text-white"> Welcome to my awesome Blog </h3>
                    <p class="text-light">Great Post to help you with your day! &nbsp
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
            {% for post in post_list %}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6"> {{ post.created}} </p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{post.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.
class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created')
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

my blog/urls

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail')
]
```

urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide a context in view, object_list is the default context when you are using class based view.
so you can iterate the queryset as object_list

```
           {% for post in object_list %}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6"> {{ post.created}} </p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{post.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Other options are to set `model = Post` or `context_object_name = 'post_list'` in the view, then `post_list` will be available in the template. See the docs on [friendly template contexts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts).

Comment: @Alasdair i have been trying to make it work the way you said but i cant come up with anything can you put a code so i can reference it